# How does the xml:lang & lang attribute affect the rendering of XHTML Strict 1.0 pages?

Tags: xml, xhtml, internationalization

I peeked inside the source of a public website which uses the XHTML 1.0 Strict DOCTYPE and noticed that it specifies two attribute related to the language of the page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
```

The page is in Japanese by the way. My question is this:-

I suspect that the attribute *xml:lang* & *lang* do not affect the rendering of the page in the browsers. It is the Content-Type in the HTTP Header which specifies the encoding of the page. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1) says:

> Language information specified via the lang attribute may be used by a user agent to control rendering in a variety of ways. Some situations where author-supplied language information may be helpful include:
>
> - Assisting search engines
> - Assisting speech synthesizers
> - Helping a user agent select glyph variants for high quality typography
> - Helping a user agent choose a set of quotation marks
> - Helping a user agent make decisions about hyphenation, ligatures, and spacing
> - Assisting spell checkers and grammar checkers

Aside from that, I wouldn't imagine it would affect layout or the document mode (quirks mode vs standards mode). [PPK's Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org) is pretty much the standard reference when it comes to things like this, and searching that site shows no mention of the lang attribute.

Comment: It might cause line-height changes, if it uses different glyph variants. As far as I know, it doesn't though.